# CimInstance Associators return an invalid path error

Tags: powershell, cim

I would like to retrieve a spefic network adapter configuration.
When I do it with its DeviceID, it works well

```
Get-CimInstance -Query `
  "Associators of {Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID=3} Where ResultClass=Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
```

However, when I try with its NetConnectionID

```
Get-CimInstance -Query `
  "Associators of {Win32_NetworkAdapter.NetConnectionID='External'} Where ResultClass=Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
```

this throw an invalid path error.

of, I could do this

```
Get-CimInstance -Query `
  "Associators of {Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID=$((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID = 'External'").DeviceID)} Where ResultClass=Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
```

but the double `Get-CimInstance` is actually not optimized

The goal is to renew a DHCP Lease for a specific named adapter

```
Get-CimInstance -Query `
  "Associators of {Win32_NetworkAdapter.NetConnectionID='External'} Where ResultClass=Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" | 
  Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName RenewDHCPLease
```

Thanks

Comment: You can only use `Key` properties to resolve instances by path - `DeviceID` is the only such property on Win32_NetworkAdapter.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, so the only way is the bad one with 2 `Get-CimInstance` ?

Comment: Yeah, you can make it slightly more elegant (and natively supporting multiple interfaces) by using the pipeline: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID = 'External'" |Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` - but yes, you will need two calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can only construct CIM/WMI object paths using *key* properties - and the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class only defines one key property: the `DeviceID`.

So yes, you'll need to perform two queries, but I would strongly recommend using the pipeline to construct the operation, as this will allow PowerShell to retrieve the associated configuration for *multiple* adapters, should the first query return more than one:

```
$adapterConfigs = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID = 'External'" |Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```